# What is matrix norm in proof of Inverse Function Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

See [PlanetMath: proof of inverse function theorem](https://planetmath.org/proofofinversefunctiontheorem).

What is the usual definition of $||A||$ for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$?

Comment: The proof of the inverse function theorem uses the operator norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite dimensional vector space all norms are equivalent, that's why in the given link, the norm is not specified. If you want to have a particular norm just think of matrix $A$ as an $n^2$ tuple and use the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: There are other norms for $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, but as user0977 was saying, they're all [equivalent](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofThatAllNormsOnFiniteVectorSpaceAreEquivalent.html).

Comment: @Jesse: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking that the induced and componentwise norms were nonequivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The usual norm is the "operator norm" induced from the norms on the vector spaces that A maps from and to, defined as $\sup\{||Ax||:||x||=1\}$; in your case, it's probably the square root of the largest eigenvalue of A*A, where A* is the conjugate transpose of A: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm